# Fl_Scroll initial scroll values

Tags: fltk

I'm using [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/) for a project (the version distributed with Debian/sid 1.3.2-6+b1) and I'm having some trouble initializing [`Fl_Scroll`](http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/classFl__Scroll.html)'s content scroll values.

I create a `Fl_Double_Window` and on the right side a vertical panel using `Fl_Scroll`, it is positioned at left **x 600** and top **y 24**.

Then I set `Fl_Scroll`'s type to `Fl_Scroll::VERTICAL` and place a `Fl_Button` inside, everything works fine.

The problem? `Fl_Scroll` initialize already scrolled with [`xposition() = 600` and `yposition() = 24`](http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/classFl__Scroll.html#ac8524eff98eebe512df6beef478fcc77) (X and Y of the Fl_Scroll's constructor?? Is supposed to work so?), instead I want it to initialize with content scrolled at left and top `0, 0`, so I tried [`scroll_to()`](http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/classFl__Scroll.html#afbf72e70c229d85bbd3716c21d43e5aa) in different places, before and after window's `show()`, on `FL_SHOW` of the subclassed `Fl_Scroll` (I didn't really need to subclass `Fl_Scroll`, just trying to get `scroll_to()` working), also on overridden `draw()` after 
the parent `draw()`, even creating `Fl_Scroll` at 0, 0 then `position()` at 600, 24, but nothing.

The only way I got `scroll_to()` working is if I call it from an async event after the application initialize (`FL_KEYUP`).

Here's the overridden Fl_Double_Window window constructor:

```
group = new Fl_Group(0, 0, WIN_W, WIN_H);
{
 menu = new Fl_Menu_Bar(0, 0, WIN_W, MENU_H);
 menu->add("File/Quit",   FL_CTRL+'q', cbMenuQuit_i);

 glview = new CGLView(0, MENU_H, WIN_W-PROPS_W+1, WIN_H-MENU_H);
 group->resizable(glview);

 scroll = new CScroll(WIN_W-PROPS_W, MENU_H, PROPS_W-1, WIN_H-MENU_H);
 scroll->type(Fl_Scroll::VERTICAL);
 {
  Fl_Pack *pack = new Fl_Pack(0, 0, PROPS_W-1, WIN_H-1);
  {
   btnAddLayer = new Fl_Button(0, 0, PROPS_W, 32, "@#+ Add Layer");
   btnAddLayer->callback(btnAddLayerCb_i, (void *)this);
  }
  pack->end();
 }
 scroll->end();
}
group->end();

end();
size_range(WIN_MIN_W, WIN_MIN_H); /* Make the window resizable */
show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, got it, two altenative:

- create `Fl_Scroll` at 0, 0 then `position()` it after `scroll->end()`
- create `Fl_Scroll` at the wanted position then after `scroll->end()` use negative values `scroll_to(-X, -Y)`

In both cases is important that the widgets contained are already added (`scroll_to()` alter cotained widgets coords)

Isn't clear to me why X and Y of `Fl_Scroll`'s *constructor* are used.

Comment: Have a look at test/scroll.cxx for an example of how to use Fl_Scroll with Fl_DoubleWindow.

Comment: Thank you @cup, I didn't thought about examples/test within fltk sources, they're not included in Debian fltk packages, downloaded. Still, all the examples I've seen online just offset at 0,0 or don't care about the initial scroll. I suspect is a bug, don't see how setting the window relative x, y for the scroll could be a feature, try `Fl_Scroll scroll(50,50,5*75-50,300-50);` with `test/scroll.cxx`

Comment: x and y in the Fl_Scroll constructor, like all other FLTK widgets, are for positioning the widget.  They do not set the position.of the cursor.  Position will also set the position of the widget.

Comment: scroll->end() just indicates that you have finished adding widgets to the scroll group.  As you have discovered, scroll_to is the one that positions the cursor.

Comment: Sorry @cup maybe I been not clear enough, my bad, one last try, `Fl_Scroll` initialize the scrollbars *already scrolled* with x, y given in `Fl_Scroll`'s `ctor()`, which doesn't make any sense to me. I'm well aware about what you say in your comments about `x, y` and `end()`, but thanks